# .val() not capturing the textbox value when button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button, sql-update

I'm trying to enter a value into the text box and have it trigger an update statement to the database, but the post `.val()` is returning a blank value.

Here's the function:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
     function save_a9(id) {
        $.post('response6.php', {starID:id, starURL: $('#starurl').val()}, 
            function(result) { 
                alert(result); 
                window.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here's the button and text box:

```
    echo "<br><b>request to join site: {$row9['count']}</b><br>";
while ($row99 = $prep99->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row99['starID']} , {$row99['starName']} = {$row99['twitter']}";
    if ($row99['guest'] == 0) {
        $guest = 'ongoing';
    };
    if ($row99['guest'] == 1) {
        $guest = 'guest';
    };
    if ($row99['guest'] == 2) {
        $guest = 'PLEASE SELECT ONE';
    };
    echo " ~ $guest ~ <br>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='starurl' value='{$row99['starURL']}' id='starurl' style='width:100px; height:30px;'/>";
    echo "<br><button onclick='save_a9({$row99['starID']})'>Approve</button><button onclick='save_d9({$row99['starID']})'>Disapprove</button><br>";
}
```

And here's response6.php:

```
<?php
include("db_conn.php");
$sql = "update stars set approved = 1, starURL = ? where starID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_POST['starURL'], $_POST['starID']));
echo 'saved';
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you may not be executing the function with the parameters you're hoping for.  Any chance you could add a jsfiddle?

Comment: How many `<input>` elements do you have on the page? If you have more than one the IDs must be unique. Non-unique IDs could give this problem.

Comment: run `$('[id="starurl"]').length` in the console to see whether there is duplicate ids

Comment: i can't figure out how to get jsfiddle to work sorry. i only have 1 input and how do i use this: `$('[id="starurl"]').length`

Comment: I guess that `$('#starurl').val()` returns a value, but somehow your server cannot get it. Try `console.log($('#starurl').val());` to see if there is a value.

Comment: this `console.log($('#starurl').val());` shows this: `(an empty string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the attribute id instead. For example

```
<button id="button-id">Click me</button>
```

and use it in jQuery. [Example of Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/).

Comment: ok but how would it work for my project? will it still be able to do all the things i'm looking for aka using the textbox value to update the database field?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I missed out getting the value of #starurl. I see that it is in a loop so I assume it generates more than one #starurl. I find that jQuery will get the first input in the list. Hence if you enter value in other than first input box, jQuery will not get the value. http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/2/

Comment: how does this work with the ajax and update query? still not quite understanding it and i need to use more than one textbox like starurl and starimage...

Comment: Your intention is to get the value of #starurl, right? Your while loop will generates HTML which uses the same id for all <input>, i.e. starurl. HTML id can only exists once on each page. If it need to appear multiple times, use class instead. I hope this updated example helps. http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/2/

Comment: it looks the same and the put it in the function and response6 code above

Comment: Silly me. I did not hit the update button. Try to check now - http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/9/

Comment: kinda like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/10/ but now I have to work it into function and response6 code above though

Comment: yes now your on the right track, how do i link it to ajax and update statement stuff?

Comment: I have this http://jsfiddle.net/JY36x/21/ I need it to loop and each time add 1 to the id=starurl part, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: From your code above it seems that you're using while loop to generate the HTML. Why not do it there as well?

Comment: because I can't figure out how to and i'm getting all confused, code to help me do that would be a great help

Comment: currently trying sessions to get the textbox value to the response6.php